# docker desktop create bind mount /mnt/e/test , but seem not correct?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL 2 with docker for desktop
i create a docker with bind mount /mnt/e/test
but in the windows OS , E:\test folder , seem nth, even i try to echo a file in docker.

in the WSL /mnt/e is referral to WIndows host E driver. i can see file inside wsl /mnt/e
anyone know how to mount a windows folder inside docker?

and now where is the file store? in the docker, i saw bind mount to /mnt/e/test

i can mount the Windows host volume by -v "E:\test:/data" but i want to know where is /mnt/e ?
Thanks

try to see \wsl$\docker-desktop-data\mnt but cannot access e